# insert 2 List into tag <c:forEach> for loop Lists synchronously

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to insert 2 List(orders and prices) into a page(.jsp) and loop 2 list synchronously.I just know insert 1 list into , what is the solution insert 2 LIST into page(jsp) for loop synchronously that, i don't know solution for issue this. THANK ALL.

File:UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{userName}", params = "mada", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ordersOfUser(Model uiModel,@PathVariable("userName")String userName){

        List<Order> orders = orderService.findAllWithUsername(userName);
        List<Float> prices = new ArrayList<Float>();
        for(int i=0;i<orders.size();i++){
            prices.add(orderService.countPrice(orders.get(i).getId()));
        }

        uiModel.addAttribute("orders",orderService.findAllWithUsername(userName));
        uiModel.addAttribute("prices",prices);

        return "orders/orderofuser";

    }
```

File:orderofuser.jsp

```
<body>
    <TABLE>
        <c:forEach items="${orders}" var="i">
            <tr>
                <td><B>ID</B></td>
                <td>${i.id}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Order Date</td>
                <TD>${i.orderDate}</TD>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Number</td>
                <td>${i.number}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <TD>Description</TD>
                <td>${i.description}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>${i.status}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>"?"</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>-------------------------------------------</td>
                <td>-------------------------------------------</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </TABLE>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *synchronously*?

Comment: What is the relationship between `orders` and `prices`?

Comment: each order have 1 price

Comment: sorry, my mother tongue isn't language. i want, when the loop retrieve orders List, it retrieve prices List in same loop. Each order has 1 price. Thank PM 77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google for "jsp foreach index" and you find the `varStatus` attribute which stores an `index` and a `count` attribute for 0- and 1-based index to where you are in the list.

Just do something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${orders}" var="order" varStatus="status">
<tr>
    <td><B>ID</B></td>
    <td>${order.id}</td>
</tr>
.
.
.
<tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>${prices.get(status.index)}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting two seperate lists for your orders and prices on your jsp, then use nested loop as following:

```
<c:forEach items="${orders}" var="order">
<tr>
    <td><B>ID</B></td>
    <td>${order.id}</td>
</tr>
.
.
.
<c:forEach items="${prices}" var="price">
    <c:if test="${order.id == price.orderId}"> // check if this price is of above order
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>${price.value}</td> // whatever you have properties in your prices list.
        </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
.
.
.
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: It means that you just have prices in your price list that a single price is float value, then how will you relate the price with order?

Your price list should contain the order id through which you can identify that the price x is of order a.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the **ORDERS** and **PRICES** in a single bean and then you can iterate the list containing object of new bean.

You can modify your Order bean class and add price as a field in that, and it will look like :

```
public class Orders {


    private String id;
    private String orderDate;
    private String number;
    private String description;
    private String status;
    private String price;

  // with getters and setters

}
```

In your order service class's findAllWithUsername(userName); method you can apply logic to add price for each order which you are doing in the UserController.

Hope this would help.

Comment: please! Can you make a example for me?Thank!